# Matrix Properties: The Inverse of a Matrix

Tags: matrices

I have a reasonably general question on the purpose 'inverting a matrix'.

Essentially, I am teaching myself some matrix algebra (lunch times at work, and so forth).

My sticking points so far concern the logic of certain steps in matrix algebra: i.e. why do we take the inverse of a matrix?

Would be useful (and extremely generous and informative) if someone could present a numerical example.

The closest explanation I could find on-line is the 'inverse is useful for  decrypting a coded message'. It would be useful to see an applied example, whether in finance, engineering, cyrptography.

Look forward to any feedback,

Best,

Andrew

Comment: If you think of a matrix as a **linear transformation** that rotates, scales and skews space (taking basis vectors to new ones), the inverse matrix is another matrix that *reverses* that rotation, scaling, or skew.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. My overarching question however is: why? Why would you need to do this in a practical example?

Comment: Linear systems of equations are incredibly applicable because many natural systems follow linear relationships. Linear systems can be wrapped up into a neat package as matrix-vector multiplication: $\boldsymbol{Ax} = \boldsymbol{b}$ which also has a geometric meaning in the context of linear transformations.

Comment: The equation $\boldsymbol{Ax} = \boldsymbol{b}$ represents a vector $x$ that is *transformed* into $b$ by rotating, skewing, scaling. Then to find $x$ given $b$, you'd want to replay the transformation *backwards*. I recommend searching for 3Blue1Brown's series on the Essence of Linear Algebra.

Comment: This also explains why nonrectangular matrices do not have inverses: they cross dimensions in which you lose information to play the transformation backwards

Comment: For many of the same reasons that you might divide by a number when working with scalar equations.